# Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node- sass/releases/download/v4.5.2/darwin-x64-57_binding.node" error. What does this mean?

Tags: meteor

I've created used Meteor to create an APP that communicates with some hardware through MQTT using Mosquitto. It was done on a Linux computer and everyone went fine. Now I've loaded the files onto OSX and I'm getting the following error with it. I've tried updates sass to the latest verson and then redoing npm install, but to no avail.

```
=> A patch (Meteor 1.7.0.5) for your current release is available!
   Update this project now with 'meteor update --patch'.
   Errors prevented startup:

While loading package materialize:materialize@0.100.2:
error: Command failed: /Users/random/.meteor/packages/meteor- tool/.1.7.0_4.x53m8m.ifru9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/npm rebuild --update-binary
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node- sass/releases/download/v4.5.2/darwin-x64-57_binding.node":                           HTTP error 404 Not Found
 Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
  try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g. 

  export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

 or configure npm proxy via

  npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

Comment: Entering `https://github.com/sass/node-%20sass/releases/download/v4.5.2/darwin-x64-57_binding.node` in my browser addressbar returns `not found`. Are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: No, I'm not now that you mention it. This is a project I'm taking over from another dev in mid production. It seemed to work perfectly fine on my Linux machine, and now on OSX it's giving me this error.

Answer (score 18):

I have found a solution.

1. Remove the `node_modules` folder
2. Remove the `package-lock.json` file
3. Clear npm cache with

> npm cache clean

4. Install the last version

> npm install node-sass@latest
>
> npm rebuild node-sass

5. Modify package.json from your project to new version of node-sass
   Run

> npm i

If you have another dependency that use node-sass change her version

Answer (score 8):

Remove package-lock.json then npm install, again. Worked for me.

(No need to remove node modules)

Comment: Exactly!.. This must be answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: This works for me.